# English bibliography in an otherwise german LaTeX document

Tags: bibliographies, languages

I have a LaTeX document in German. The only thing I want in English are the entries of the bibliography. How do I do this?

Here is my minimal working example:

my `main.tex` document:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=ieee, citestyle=numeric-comp, natbib=true, sorting=none]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{bibfile.bib} %The filename of the bibliography

\begin{document}

\chapter{SomeExampleChapter, with Kapitel, not chapter..}
example of a citation \cite{Reference1}.   Here everything is in german, e.g.  Abbildung statt figure,  Kapitel instead of chapter etc...

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]  

\end{document}
```

and my `bibfile.bib`:

```
@article{Reference1,
    Author = {C. J. Hawthorn and K. P. Weber and R. E. Scholten},
    Journal = {Rev. Sci. Instrum.},
    Number = {12},
    Pages = {4477--4479},
    Title = {Littrow Configuration Tunable External Cavity Diode Laser with Fixed Direction Output Beam},
    Year = {2001}
}
```

So far the bibliography reads:   `C. J. Hawthorn, K.P. Weber und R.E. Scholten`

I want it to be: `C. J. Hawthorn, K.P. Weber and R.E. Scholten`

The **und** should be changed to **and**.  Apart from that, nothing should be changed.

I know similar questions have been asked, but I struggled with all the answers there.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! With the `autolang=other` option of biblatex, you can add the field `langid` to specify the language used for bibliography items on an individual basis.

Comment: umm after adding `autolang=other` to the options of biblatex and adding the line `langid={english},` in the bibfile.bib, I get the error:  Package babel Error: Unknown language 'english'. Either you have (babel) install it or just rerun the file, respectively.  I tried to fix that error with `\usepackage[english,german]{babel}`, but it didn't work..

Comment: @AntonRodenhauser: In this case remove either the `.aux` file or rerun (as suggested in the message)

Comment: The language options of babel should be loaded with the document class since version 3.9. Please see a full code which works with the standard `report` class. Maybe there's a problem with the class you load?

Comment: @Bernard: MastersDoctorialThesis (MDT) is said to have issues ... ask Johannes_B ;-)

Comment: Well, that's another problem. But I can't test whatever. Is the problem the same with `biber` as a backend?

Comment: I concur with Bernard that `autolang=other` coupled with `langid` for each entry would be the most interesting approach. But if really **all** entries in the bibliography should be in English, than perhaps `\selectlanguage{english}` before `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Literatur}]` could get the job done. Of course, `english` would have to be set for babel.

Comment: Another issue here is that both `autolang=other` + `langid` and `selectlanguage` will likely change other things in your references besides "and" instead of "und". It will use bibstrings for English rather than German in general. The `autolang=other` + `langid` approach allows you to use English bibstrings for English references and German bibstrings for German ones.

Comment: As said before, you have to add `english` before ` ngerman` to the documentclass options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I don't have the `MastersDoctoralThesis` class, I replaced it with `report`, und this code works fine for me:

```
\documentclass[english, ngerman]{report}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=ieee, citestyle=numeric-comp, natbib=true, sorting=none, autolang=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{bibfile.bib} %The filename of the bibliography

\begin{document}

\chapter{SomeExampleChapter, with Kapitel, not chapter..}
example of a citation \cite{Reference1}. Here everything is in german, e.g. Abbildung statt figure, Kapitel instead of chapter etc...
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

[image]